# Receiving the TypeError: r is not a function

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am receiving the following error highlighting `callback(result);`:

*Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function at Image.onload (webp-support.js:6)*

**Exporting File (webp-support.js):**

```
export default (callback) => {
    let img = new Image();

    img.onload = _ => {
        let result = (img.width > 0) && (img.height > 0);
        callback(result);
    }
    img.onerror = _ => {
        callback(false);
    }

    img.src = "data:image/webp;base64,UklGRiIAAABXRUJQVlA4IBYAAAAwAQCdASoBAAEADsD+JaQAA3AAAAAA";
}
```

**Importing File:**

```
import webpSupport from './webp-support';

webpSupport(console.log('hello'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
webpSupport(console.log('hello'));
```

If we break it down, you'll see the problem:

```
let supportedCallback = console.log('hello');
webpSupport(supportedCallback);
```

That obviously doesn't work. It does the `console.log` then assigns the result of that (`undefined`, always) as the callback in your `webpSupport` function. Clearly you don't want that. You need to pass a function that itself calls `console.log`:

```
webpSupport(() => console.log('webp supported'));
```

I've also taken the liberty of logging a more helpful message than `hello`! If you're not familiar with it, the `() => ...` syntax is Javascript's shorter function syntax, known as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).